# column borders in asp.net table controls

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net and using it to create a form. I have a table control, in which I need to put visible borders only between columns. I dont need the border anywhere else. Is there a way to do this and if yes, how?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would assign a css class to your table cells that had definitions for border-left and border-right set to the color and thickness you'd like.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, would go ahead and give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do css and set borders colors but easier is just with simple format like in ms word. Tick whole column and go to format -> boders and shading there is everything you need.